# Assign value by filtering rows based on two conditions with loc and isin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, isin

I am trying to assign a value 'FL' to my column 'FL_PL' with the following code the value 'FL'is not assigned in that column. Nothing is assign. I only get a column of True and False in the output (not in the df).

```
size_types = ['small', 'micro']
pl_types = ['1', '11', '32']
df2.loc[(df2['SIZE'].isin(size_types)) &
        (df2['TYPE'].isin(pl_types)), 'PL_FL'] == 'FL'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `=` to assign the value, `==` is the [equality](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) operator:

```
df2.loc[df2['SIZE'].isin(size_types) &
        df2['TYPE'].isin(pl_types), 'PL_FL'] = 'FL'
```

Comment: Thanks, are the brackets need before & and after &? df2.loc[(df2['SIZE'].isin(size_types) &
        df2['TYPE'].isin(pl_types)), 'PL_FL'] = 'FL

Comment: @S_Star you mean parenthesis? No, they can be skiped  - `df2.loc[df2['SIZE'].isin(size_types) & df2['TYPE'].isin(pl_types), 'PL_FL'] = 'FL'`

Comment: Yes, thank you. So, I only use paranthesis when I use OR, with AND is not needed. That is my conclusion.

Comment: @S_Star This is not correct. You use parenthesis for any logic operators in cases where the syntax is ambiguous/will be misinterpreted. For example, if you wrote something like `df2['Size'] == 'small' & df['pl_types'] == '1'`, it is likely to raise an error because it will be executed like `df2['Size'] == ('small' & df['pl_types']) == '1'` instead of `(df2['Size'] == 'small') & (df['pl_types'] == '1')`. In your case, your criteria is stated in a way that doesn't have that same ambiguity so the parenthesis are not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes, I meant in my case that parenthesis are not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `==` which is a comparison operator and not `=` which is the assignment operator.